# ¿Como hacer un cUrl adjuntando varias fotos o videos en App Facebook?

Tags: curl, php8, facebook-api, laravel-10

***Estoy investigando la manera de como hacer un cUrl que publique fotos o videos como en App Facebook pero de manera pueda subir mas de uno y me refiero a una publicación que tenga más de una foto o video***

Aquí hay ejemplo de publicar una foto en facebook:
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/photos?url={path-to-photo}&access_token={page-access-token}"

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.